# Rendering is ok, I see the sofa till finishing, after the rendering finished, there is only white screen on the rendering screen

Tags: rendering

I tried with different scene and the result is the same.

[image]

Here is an image of my compositor screen

Comment: hello, make sure that there's not an object that is enabled for rendering in the Outliner. Or please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: the same error is with 3 different files, which are not mine.

Comment: hard to tell without the file  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that *Image* data from *Render Layers* isn't connected to the *Denoise* node.

Try connecting a noodle here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try , and than rendering after 2 hours I will write  what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @ Allen Simpson and all who gave advices!!!! Allen Simpson's idea worked perfect. In compositor I connect 'image " in Render Layers with "image" in Denoise". Than rendering and woala great render in png , which I saved successfully :)
Thank you very much!